# Mvc 3 razor view engine complaining about missing model in auto generated code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I will try to keep this question short..(try)

I extended RazorViewEngine like this

```
public class MyViewEngine:RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyViewEngine(array viewPathCollection)
    {
        //My views are all embedded resources and here I   
        //set ViewLocationFormats and PartialViewLocationFormats 
        //so that MyVirtualPathProvider can find them inside the assembly
    }
    protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        //Some Logic to check for file
    }
}
```

Then in Global.asax Application_Start did this

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new AssemblyResourceViewEngine(ViewPathCollection.ToArray()));
```

Now when I run(all hooks in place) I get this compilation error in the browser

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:

```
public override void Execute() {
  Write(model);
  WriteLiteral(" MyModelClass \r\n\r\n");
```

And on clicking Show complete compilation source i see this

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.225
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ASP {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Helpers;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.WebPages;
    using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
    using Automotive.Web.Core.Utilities;


    public class _Page_bin_MyProject_DLL_Views_Home_Index_cshtml : System.Web.WebPages.WebPage {

#line hidden
        public _Page_bin_MyProject_DLL_Views_Home_Index_cshtml() {       
        }

        protected ASP.global_asax ApplicationInstance {
            get {
                return ((ASP.global_asax)(Context.ApplicationInstance));
            }
        }

        public override void Execute() {

Write(model);

WriteLiteral(" MyModelClass \r\n\r\n");

WriteLiteral("Hello, this is the only thing in the view");
        }
    }
}
```

Additional Info:

I have extended the VirtualPathProvider to find my views inside different assemblies. 
I do this in Application_start to register MyVirtualPathProvider

```
HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new MyVirtualPathProvider());
```

If you need clarifications on this question, please let me know. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post your razor view source. `model` is not a valid property of `System.Web.WebPages.WebPage` it's `Model`.

Comment: Solved..... copying the webconfig file from the views folder into the bin folder does it.. Dont really like the solution though...might have to rethink the structure...

Comment: Awesome. Post your solution as an answer and accept it so that other's will find an answer if they have a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved..... copying the webconfig file from the views folder into the bin folder does it.. Dont really like the solution though...might have to rethink the structure

Comment: Hi I'm having this problem too, but your solution isn't working for me... should be copying the web.config from the host apps views into the bin folder of the host app, or of the web project containing my embedded resources? thanks!

Comment: if you have razor views as embedded resources in a dll, add the webconfig from the view folder into the folder with the dll. The webconfig adds assemblies required by the razor view engine.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't like the idea to copy the web.config in View folder to the bin, here is my solution.

Add the following codes in configSections in the root web.config

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Add new section

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```